# Compiling QVision

Tags: qt, warnings

I'm trying to compile `QVision` under Windows as instructed here: http://qvision.sourceforge.net/DownloadAndSetup.html

When I do that, I get the following in `Qt Creator`:

> ```
> c:\Users\Medicine - SWEng\Desktop\qvision.0.6.0\common.pri:37:
> ```
>
> warning: Unable to find file for
>   inclusion config.pri

And,

`:-1: error: File config.pri not present. Read the INSTALL file, and modify config.pri.example to generate it.`

**UPDATE:**

After solving the preceding error by renaming `config.pri.example` to `config.pri`, I now get the following warning:

`c:\Users\Medicine - SWEng\Desktop\qvision.0.6.0\config.pri:43: warning: Unescaped backslashes are deprecated.`

This error still remains even though I changed the path to where QVision is saved as follows: `INSTALL_PATH=C:\Users\Medicine - SWEng\Desktop\qvision.0.6.0`

I'm also getting this warning:

`c:\Users\Medicine - SWEng\Desktop\qvision.0.6.0\src\qvgsl.pri:31: warning: Unescaped backslashes are deprecated.`

The error I'm getting is:

`:-1: error: In module qvmplayer: QVMPlayer binary was not found at: /usr/bin/mplayer . Set a correct path in the MPLAYER_BINARY_PATH variable at the config.pri file`

Any ideas on that?

Thanks.

Comment: The error message says what you should do, does it not work? Also, see the page you linked http://qvision.sourceforge.net/DownloadAndSetup.html#QVisionConfiguration

Answer (score 2):

Read the install documentation you pointed to:

> You *must rename* the file config.pri.example to config.pri. This file contains several parameters and options that configure the compilation and functionallity of the QVision.
>
> ... Open the file config.pri with a text editor, and **read carefully the instructions** contained in that file about how to tune each configuration parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Warnings for "Unescaped backslashes are deprecated" are due to the content in variables INSTALL_PATH and GSL_PATH, in the 'config.pri' file. Read for example:

http://www.qtforum.org/article/33409/unescaped-backslashes-are-deprecated.html